# link is on other parts of div

Tags: html, css

So I have here a button that i made but when i hover over a place like below it not in the button you can click on the link how do i solve this

```css
#box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  left: 560px;
  bottom: 55px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div id="Box">Back to safety</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Get rid of the nested `div` inside the `a` element and give the `id=Box` to the `a` element.

Comment: you set : height and width to the box, which is the area where you link stands and is clikable. :) , but here your selector is **`#Box`** and id is **`box`**. B & b are different :(

Comment: Thanks Scott that helped me but i had to change height and width to padding. Also GCyrillus the b and B were not the problem because the rest of the style wouldnt have worked if i messed up on that